# Cannot select iframe loaded

Tags: javascript, php, console

How can I select my loaded iframe that it can't be selected even it is loaded ?

When I type this in console

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="typeform"]');
```

It returns undefined 
Even my iframe which is loaded from typeform is shown .

Thanks in advance

This is an image to explain more my question
[image: The buton of typeform is stuck on the other internal button , I want to move the button of the typeform a little bit verticaly]

The buton of typeform is stuck on the other internal button , I want to move the button of the typeform a little bit vertically

Comment: We can hardly tell you anything with that little information. Provide a proper [mre], please.

Comment: check my edit @misorude

Comment: Showing a mere screenshot does not explain what you are actually doing any better. Again: [mre], please.

Comment: Sorry the code is a bit confidential that is why I can't publish , added to that for those who have used before typeform they can have with the image below an idea about the problem, thanks anyway

Comment: Hi Ahmed, what is your main issue?
The typeform button is hidden under another button of yours? Did you try to reduce the height of the typeform iframe?

Comment: Thanks @NicolasGrenié , yeah that is it the main problem , I can't reduce the height of the typeform height. I tried with jquery but that doesn't work

Comment: $('iframe[src*="typeform"]').css("min-height", "90%");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

```
iframe[src*="typeform"] {
min-height: 94% !important;
max-height: 94% !important;
}
```