# Customize typeform button

Tags: jquery, html, css, typeform

I want to change typeform Button (embedded) position or at least change the iframe gotten by typeform height.

You can see my essay here in this question
[Cannot select iframe loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286692/cannot-select-iframe-loaded?noredirect=1#comment101122993_57286692)

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="typeform"]');
```

I expect to get a button a little bit higher but the default is not what is expected
I have solved the problem using selectors level 3

```
The solution

iframe[src*="typeform"] {
min-height: 94% !important;
max-height: 94% !important;
}
```

I have added the answer below
original post
[Cannot select iframe loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286692/cannot-select-iframe-loaded)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286692/cannot-select-iframe-loaded

Comment: You can return to the question and if it is duplicated or not, here I am speaking about height also

Comment: `I want to move the button of the typeform a little bit vertically` seems to refer to the same.

Comment: Whether it is or not , any help please, Thanks

Comment: Problem solved check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem using selectors level 3 
Hope help anyone else

```
iframe[src*="typeform"] {
min-height: 94% !important;
max-height: 94% !important;
}
```